# Import Numpy = attributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'core'

Tags: python, scripting, animation-nodes

I have been trying to load Animation Nodes, but can't seem to get Numpy to work, and have no idea how to install. I have done a clean install on latest version (and other tower works fine) but this particular machine won't work. I have not had to install Numpy on the working machine. The Numpy folder has been installed, I even copied it to the Modules folder, and it still won't work.

I really need to use these nodes.

When I try import I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\scripts\modules\numpy\__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\scripts\modules\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\scripts\modules\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\scripts\modules\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
     import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'core'
```

Comment: I think this relates to library loading on your system. See if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37733943/2684771) provides enough info to resolve the issue. I'm not sure of the equivalent in windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numpy in Blender 2.77a](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61980/numpy-in-blender-2-77a)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because appears to be an AN bug and should be reported to the [AN bug tracker](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/issues).

Answer (score 1):

## Blender installation issue

Blender comes with numpy installed. Maybe something got wrong in your blender installation, if so you should not be able to import numpy directly from the python console:  (deactivate AN first)

[image: Numpy Test]

If these simple commands do work, this means AN is the problem and you should create an issue thread on [the github repo](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/) or contact Jacques Luke directly.
If they don't work, it means Blender wasn't installed correctly, and you should try:

- to copy directly the site-packages folder at `%version%\python\lib\site-packages` directory. (Download the blender zip and copy the directory).
- As I have not tried it myself, maybe the last method will create conflicts, so if it doesn't work, make a new installation of blender.

Answer (score 0):

"pip install --user --upgrade numpy"
run this in cmd

Comment: Blender uses a bundled python install not on the system path, and should already include numpy. I don't think this will work as it stands.